# i3wm: How to automatically switch workspace when a window of a specific application requests focus?

Tags: window-manager, i3, focus

I tried `focus_on_window_activation` with `focus`, but it doesn't do anything. I guess it only works on same workspace. Or maybe I am using it wrong?

```
for_window [class="Chromium"] focus_on_window_activation focus
```

For example in a Thunderbird when I click on a link, I want Chromium to get focus and switch to its workspace (only Chromium, not all applications). Currently it only gets the urgency flag (I believe its usually visualized by a red background of a workspace "button" in a bar).

Answer (score 0):

If you add

```bash
for_window [urgent="latest"] focus
```

to your `~/.i3/config`, then i3 will automatically focus a window once it becomes urgent.

In your case you could combine criteria if you only want to focus certain applications:

```bash
for_window [urgent="latest" class="Chromium"] focus
```

Comment: After adding switching to Chromium's default workspace, it works fairly well: `for_window [urgent="latest" class="Chromium" workspace=$ws1] focus ; workspace number $ws1`. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately I spoke too soon. The solution above is unreliable, a lot of times it simply does nothing. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about urgent windows at all, you can simply do

```
focus_on_window_activation focus
```

[From the docs:](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#focus_on_window_activation)

> `focus`
> The window will always be focused and not be marked urgent.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working consistently by modifying both the `focus_on_window_activation` and `for_window` settings.

```
focus_on_window_activation focus
for_window [class="^Firefox$"] focus
```